Is a randomly restarted Markov process again Markov?
Let $E$ be a topological space and $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a right-continuous time-homogeneous Markov process with transition semigroup $(P_t)_{t\ge0}$ on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0},\operatorname P)$. Moreover, let $\tau:\Omega\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal A$-measurable.

I want to know under which conditions $$Y_t:=X_{\tau+t}\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ is again a (time-homogeneous) $(\mathcal G_t)_{t\ge0}$-Markov process with transition semigroup $(Q_t)_{t\ge0}$. That is, part of this question is the identification of $(\mathcal G_t)_{t\ge0}$ and $(Q_t)_{t\ge0}$.

One sufficient condition is that $\tau$ is an $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$-stopping time. In that case we can choose $\mathcal G_t:=\mathcal F_{\tau+t}$ and $Q_t:=P_t$ for $t\ge0$.
However, I'm mostly interested in kind of the opposite assumption: I want to consider what we can say when $\tau$ is independent of $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ or maybe even independent of $\mathcal F_\infty:=\bigvee_{t\ge0}\mathcal F_t$.
I really struggle to proceed on this. $\mathcal F_{\tau+t}$ is now not even well-defined anymore (it's not guaranteed to be a $\sigma$-algebra) and so I have no idea how to choose $\mathcal G_t$. For that reason, in lack of a better idea, I first tried to proceed with the filtration $\mathcal G_t:=\mathcal F^Y_t$ generated by $Y$. I was only able to show that $$\operatorname E\left[f(Y_t)\right]=\int\operatorname P\left[\tau\in{\rm d}r\right]\operatorname E\left[(P_tf)(X_r)\right]$$ for all bounded Borel measurable $f:E\to\mathbb R$. But that is not even enough for me to identify the transition semigroup of $Y$.
(I would like to keep it general, but if it crucially helps you can assume that $\tau$ is exponentially distributed, with parameter $\alpha>0$, since this is the case I'm actually interested in).

This paper appears to be related.
